# 'Nonetype' has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord.py

In the code below I am trying to give a person a role when they react to my message by using an emoji but this code throws me an error saying that `'Nonetype' has no attribute 'id'` Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = discord.Client()





@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('ready')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
   role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Test_Bot')
   await user.add_roles(role, reason='reason')



 client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: `discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id='901100841438695534')` is returning `None`

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: Just copy and past the ID of the role how it is. Putting it into `' '` will always return errors. You only do this if you search by `name='RoleName'` so just do `id=RoleID`

Comment: Your edited code now has no `.id` attributes being referenced. We'll need the full traceback to see where the error is.

Comment: You have more information. What's the full traceback? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Should Always Try to Check That What is result we are getting

`role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id='901100841438695534')`
here you can just add one extra line to Check Whats Wrong

`print(role)`
here if you Get None , then the Error will be Given back to you, Just Remove the Blockquotes and youre fine :)

Also another thing i mention , Give The whole Traceback of the Code to make us understand easier :)

PS: After edit you Changed you are still not getting the Value of the role
as Maybe you have written a normal string role =
`role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Test_Bot')`
`role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles,name=("Test_Bot"))`(you need a extra tuple like form)

also the roles are case sensitive so make sure to use original word

Also print the role to make sure its right
TY :)

Comment: I am new to this so, I don't know what a blockquote means so can you please explain what it means

Comment: " <- in a python means a quote(or blockquote) and what you have to do is just remove it in both sides because its a integer and not a string :) and welcome to coding and making bots :)

Comment: Oh so now You Have Changed the code still you get the error? if yes i will give you my own code to give someone roles and lemme see if it works